# TypeError: 'zip' object is not callable in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to zip in Python 3.8, and can't figure out how to access the contents. I've read now that zip() is a generator, and I have to call dict(zip()) if I want to store the contents. However, I'm experiencing an error when doing so.

For example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# initialise
count_vec = CountVectorizer()
word_list = []
for ques_split in [ques.split() for ques in group_wise_ques_list["dbo:genre"]]:
    # convert words to lower case
    word_list.extend(list(map(str.lower,ques_split)))
print(len(set(word_list)))

group_wise_ques_list = df.groupby(["Processedrelations"])["question"].apply(list)

# transform will normalise the data (if required) and fit will perform the matrix creation
genr_tdm = count_vec.fit_transform(group_wise_ques_list["dbo:genre"])
# convert the raw matrix into a dataframe
genr_tdm_df = pd.DataFrame(genr_tdm.toarray(), columns=count_vec.get_feature_names())


# for NLP, words itself are the features, hence get_feature_names will simply return the set of words
word_list_s = count_vec.get_feature_names(); 
# count the frequency of each word
count_list_s = genr_tdm.toarray().sum(axis=0) 
# create a dictionary with each word as key and its frequency as the value
freq_s = dict(zip(word_list_s,count_list_s))
# sort the dictionary in reverse order
freq_s = sorted(freq_s.items(), key = lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)
# display
freq_s
```

i got this error

```
TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please include more details of your code. Do have, by any chance, an attribute called `zip` to which you have assigned a `ZipFile` object??

Comment: i added from zipfile import ZipFile but its not working

Comment: which line you got error?

Comment: @xsrg45 Are you working with zip files in your code? Please include that part of your code in your question.

Comment: line 6 freq_s= ...

Comment: maybe because of your `count_list_s` make sure that it should be a list

Comment: the type of count_list_s is list

Comment: @xsrg45 before the error line, add this `print(type(zip))`. Run your code again and see if it has printed this: `<class 'type'>`

Comment: @xsrg45, can you send a screenshot from your code and error on the edited post

Comment: its printed <class 'type'>

Comment: The statement you read, that "zip" is a generator, refers to the built-in function "zip" in the standard Python library.  The error message, which for some reason you refuse to give us the entire traceback for, clearly refers to an object of type ZipFile (a class in module zipfile in the standard Python library).  Not the same thing at all, even though they both start with the same three letters.  It is very probable that you have mixed these two things up in some way, perhaps by a statement like `zip = <something or other>', which would hide the built-in zip function from all later code.

Answer (score 1):

I run this code and don't get an error:

```py
count_list_s = [2,4,6,8,10,12] 
word_list_s = ['adf','bdfd','cdfd','ddfd','edfd','fdfdf']

freq_s = (dict(zip(word_list_s, count_list_s)))


freq_s = sorted(freq_s.items(), key = lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)
freq_s
```

output:

```
[('fdfdf', 12),
 ('edfd', 10),
 ('ddfd', 8),
 ('cdfd', 6),
 ('bdfd', 4),
 ('adf', 2)]
```

Comment: if you have this `from zipfile import ZipFile as zip` make sure delete this command and run code with restart kernel

Comment: i got ValueError: ZipFile requires mode 'r', 'w', 'x', or 'a'

Comment: @xsrg45,where are you run your code? Are you sure before not importing this zipfile?

Comment: on jupyter notebook

Comment: before i imported the zipfile

Comment: @xsrg45, on tab kernel, click `restart and clear output` and run only my code, see you get error or not?

Comment: i click onr estart and clear output and i got the same error